# Delete Data in their previous table

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

after getting data from different tables and save them in only 1 table. i'm done saving them in 1 table, and i want to delete the data from different table where i fetched the data. 
here is my code where i fetched the data:

```
<tr> <?php $status_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status;") or die ("Note: ". mysql_error());
?>

<td><label>Status:</label></td>
<td><select name="stat">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<?php
while($stats = mysql_fetch_array($status_query))
{
echo "<option value=".$stats['status'].">". $stats['status']. "</option>";
}
echo"</select>"
?>
<?php 
$asgn_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM assignee;") or die ("Note: " . mysql_error());
?>
<td><label>Assignee Name:</label></td>
<td><select name="assignee">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<?php
while($ass = mysql_fetch_array($asgn_query))
{
echo "<option value=".$ass['id'].">" . $ass['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select> "
?>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please help how to delete the data from different tables.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi, what exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: @Pekka웃 hello.. i'm stuck on deleting the data in different tables..

Comment: Try this `mysql_query("DELETE FROM <table_name> WHERE assignee_id=<assignee_id>");`

Comment: @JSWorld is it right to do like this:  mysql_query("DELETE FROM <table1> WHERE assignee_id=<assignee_id>");     mysql_query("DELETE FROM <table2> WHERE status_id=<status_id>");

Answer (score 0):

When you are done with saving you data right after that delete the data from the required tables like

```
<?php 

$status=$_POST['stat']; 
$assignee=$_POST['assignee'];
$status_query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM `status` WHERE `your_column`='$status'");//not sure about the column write the column name
$assignee_query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM `assignee` WHERE `id`='$assignee'");
?>
```